# Windows Service installation on Docker Container

Tags: docker, containers, windows

I am trying to port one of our Tomcat based Windows application to Windows Nano Server Container. The installation process includes two *Windows Service* installations - an ActiveMQ service and another Tomcat Service. This is achieved using two batch files provided with the product. In addition to installing the service, they also pass several arguments pertaining to JVM. Now the issue I am facing is I am not able to get these services installed on a Nano Server. The same Dockerfile works perfect and installs the product on Windows Server Core Container.

I am at a loss on how to troubleshoot this issue. Are there any limitations on Nano Server Container when it comes to Windows Services?

**Update**: I discovered that the services which get installed through batch files are dependent on two system components - Ancillary Function Driver for Winsock (Service name: afd) and TCP/IP Protocol Driver (Service Name: tcpip). I see that they are absent in a Nano Server Container but are present in Windows Server Core container. Could that be a reason? If yes, is there any way to get those services running on Nano Server?

Comment: Thank you for posting a question. Could you modify the question so that it contains the attempts you have done in order to solve the issue?